# UITextField password mode show dot immediately when typing

Tags: ios, passwords, uitextfield

We can set `secureTextEntry` property on `UITextField` to hide password. But there is a problem, when typing a number/letter,the textField would show the typing letter/number for a while before it becomes dot. What I want is when user types, the letter/number must immediately become dot. How can I achieve that, can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change that behavior by because it is built into `UITextField`. You could try to peek inside the class and see if there are any variables that you can mess with, but such code easily breaks after iOS updates.

You could use a font that [has dots instead](https://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/1106896/password_dots_2), and leave `secureTextEntry` on `false`.